# Queries on parse arrays(searching if list is empty)

Tags: android, parse-platform

How to query on Array values if I want to search for empty list ? I am currently doing:

```
query.whereEqualTo("friendsList","");
```

But, this does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
query.whereEqualTo("friendsList","");
```

this query will work only if your friend list contains an empty space ie [""] and not null ie [ ].